# Why is my code not finding the path with the largest sum?

Tags: python

I'm doing a problem that some of you may have seen before.

I'm trying to find the path with the largest sum in a tree that looks something like this:

```
   03  
 04 05  
02 03 06
```

and so forth. I copied the tree into a text file 'dataset' so it looked like this:

```
03  
04 05  
02 03 06
```

and then parsed it into a 2d array, but my two nested for loops finds the right answer in the example, but not the main problem. The answer is checked by computer, so I don't know what it should be.

```
tree = [[]]
highest = 0
f = open("dataset","r") #contains the data from the problem

for line in f: #parser
   for i in range(0,len(line),3):
      tree[-1].append(int(line[i:i+2]))
   tree.append([])
tree.pop()

for i in range(len(tree)):
   highest += tree[i][0]

total = highest

for j in range(1,len(tree)):
   for i in range(len(tree)-1,j-1,-1):
      print(i,j)
      total -= tree[i][j-1]
      total += tree[i][j]
      if(total>highest):
         highest = total

print(highest)
```

The parser does print out the complete dataset. Since this is an algorithms problem, they don't give tricky parsing problems.

The double `for` loop uses the total of all lefts, then subtracts the last number from that row and adds the new one. It parses the tree from right to left.

I thought it could be a bounds error, but I don't see it anywhere.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs?

Comment: I don't know the expected output on the dataset I'm using because the problem is checked by computer. The output for the input I showed up there would be 3+5+6 = 14. The program gets 14 for that dataset. However, it does not get the correct answer for larger datasets.

Comment: You don't use `treeparser`... Nor do you restrict yourself to valid paths. I'm afraid the whole solution is just wrong.

Comment: Your tree notation is confusing and/or ambiguous. Is the bottom 03 a child of 04 or 05, or possibly both (not properly a tree then, but a DAG)?

Comment: @JoshCaswell; How? I can't delete old comments. // Also, `tree = [[1], [1,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1,0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your indexing is off.

```
for i in range(0,len(line),3):
```

Would give you, for the line

```
2 3 6
```

the indices `0` and `3`; *not* `0`, `2` and `4`. Taking an index and slice approach to this is not very efficient, use `split`:

```
"2 3 6\n".strip().split(" ") == ['2', '3', '6']
```

Note that this will work even if you include two-digit integers.

You can convert all items in a list using `map`:

```
map(int, ['2', '3', '6']) == [2, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Your last line doesn't solve the wanted problem, but the rest is totally valid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I gave you the wrong dataset. I'll change it. All the data in the set is 2 digits.

Comment: This is a valid criticism, but my parsing solution does work for the dataset I was given. The problem is not in the parsing but when I go to find the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

On a sweep of this:

```
tree = [
      [0],
     [0,0],
    [0,1,0],
   [0,0,1,0]
]
```

Your algorithm fails. This is easy to see: by the time it gets to `3, 2` it has forgotten the 1 at `2, 1`.

I don't know of any algorithm that works without a row of auxiliary memory, so I'd just go for `aga`'s simpler solution.

I tested the code with this:

```
tree_node_cost = [
    ...
]

cost_cache = tree_node_cost[0]

for row_node_costs in tree_node_cost[1:]:
    out_cache = [0] * (len(cost_cache) + 1)

    for i, cache in enumerate(cost_cache):
        out_cache[i] = max(out_cache[i], row_node_costs[i] + cache)
        out_cache[i+1] = row_node_costs[i+1] + cache

    cost_cache = out_cache

max(cost_cache)
```

as my "trusted" code and randomly generated trees to see what differed, so there you are.